# Rails multiple params permit calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I am trying to use multiple permits in a single method similar to the following (psuedocode)

```
  def index
    model.create(
      params.permit(:b, :c)
    )
    params.permit(:a)
  end
```

This is my actual code

```
  def create
    params.permit(:create_special_categories)
    balance_sheet = ::BalanceSheet.create!(
      balance_sheet_params.merge(date: Time.zone.now.to_date, entity: @entity)
    )
    balance_sheet.create_special_categories if params[:create_special_categories]
    render json: balance_sheet, serializer: ::Api::V3::BalanceSheetSerializer
  end

  def balance_sheet_params
    params.permit(
      :id,
      :entity,
      :entity_id,
      :date,
      :name
    )
  end
```

However, I get the following error...

```
ActionController::UnpermittedParameters:
       found unpermitted parameter: :create_special_categories
```

UPDATE

my solution was to avoid strong parameters all together.

```
  def create
    balance_sheet = ::BalanceSheet.new(
      date: Time.zone.now.to_date, entity: @entity
    )
    balance_sheet.name = params[:name]
    balance_sheet.save!
    balance_sheet.create_special_categories if params[:create_special_categories]
    render json: balance_sheet, serializer: ::Api::V3::BalanceSheetSerializer
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line doesn't have any effect, `params.permit` are not chained or added to a previous `permit`, you must use the result, that is why it's almost always used in a separate method.

```
params.permit(:create_special_categories)
```

What you must do is use what that returns for your following statements

```
permitted_params = params.permit(:create_special_categories)
Model.create(permitted_params)
```

...however you really should outsource this to a special method like you already have. You will have to tweak this to your use-case obviously.

```
def balance_sheet_params
  if params[:create_special_categories]
    params.permit(:id,
        :entity,
        :entity_id,
        :date,
        :name,
        :create_special_categories)
  else
      params.permit(
        :id,
        :entity,
        :entity_id,
        :date,
        :name)
  end
end
```